# How to create a bootable USB from a macOS dmg file?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, gparted, macosx

I badly need to install macOS Sierra in a Macbook Pro (early 2015). I accidentally erase the contents of it's hard drive. The only option I have is using Internet Recovery, but I don't want to waste Internet bandwidth and the fact my connection is very very very very very slow.

I only have:

- Ubuntu 15.10-installed computer
- 64GB USB Flash Drive
- DMG file: Install macOS Sierra.dmg
- DMG file: InstallESD.dmg extracted from the DMG file mentioned above
- GParted Partition Editor
- dmg2img package, which is used to convert DMG to ISO
- hfsprogs package, which is used by GParted to create a partition having a HFS+ file system

I have tried:

- Converting the DMG files to ISO
- Formatting the USB Flash Drive with GPT as the partition table
- Creating a partition of an HFS+ file system on the USB Flash Drive
- Unmounting the USB Flash Drive before I issued the command below
- Issuing a command `$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/converted.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync`

Supposedly, I already had a bootable USB that will install macOS sierra. But when I plugged it in the Macbook Pro, turned on the computer, and pressed the `alt/option` key (which will give me options what drive to boot), only the Internet Recovery was the option. I was expecting the bootable USB to show up.

I would like to know the correct way of creating a bootable USB, for the DMG file, in Ubuntu. Let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/505821/making-a-bootable-osx-usb-from-dmg-on-linux

Comment: @Melebius I bumped already onto that but the answers are not working.  Same result, Macbook Pro is not showing the bootable USB as a startup disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing unetbootin in the ubuntu machine with the command

`sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

and using your mac iso, install it to your usb

Comment: How I'm gonna format the USB Flash Drive?

Comment: How to change `/tmp` directory? It is using the `/tmp` directory. I want to change that.